# remove border from an image which is checkbox replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this jquery plugin,

http://jordankasper.com/jquery/imagecheck/examples.php

if you see the example there is a border around the checkbox image once you click it
can anyone tell me how could I remove that..

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BSZp8/8/

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `outline` in CSS, like this:

```
.imageCheck{
   outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `outline: none` to your CSS for that element.

Answer (score 1):

Add the outline CSS, and if this is a focus rectangle you're referring to, try adding a .blur() after the plugin executes / on callback.